# How to use fscanf to obtain numbers with more than one delimiter?

Tags: c, delimiter, scanf

I'm brand new to working with c. I've got a file with the following format style:

```
number:number,number,number
```

Is there anyway I can use `fscanf` to obtain the numbers from the file?

My code below is not working:

```
fscanf(file,"%d%[^:]:%d%[^,],%d%[^,],%d",&one,something,&two,something3,&three,something4,&four);
```

Comment: Scan the entire line, and then use `strtok` instead.

Comment: @barakmanos I need to use fscanf for exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `%[^:]` parts there, you can put delimiters into the format string directly:

```
int a, b, c, d;
while (scanf("%d:%d,%d,%d",&a,&b,&c,&d) == 4) {
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a, b, c, d);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/vzyzcQ)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much man! What would be a situation where we would have to use the "%[^:]" that I was trying to put in there? Or is that simply not needed?

Comment: @Vimzy `%[^...]` format is for reading strings. You can use an asterisk after `%` to skip the corresponding input. However, usually it is not necessary when you read numbers, because `scanf` skips whitespace automatically.

Comment: @Vimzy Consider "1: 2 , 3, 4" Here an additional space _before_ comma breaks up `scanf`.